# Wrong Mouse.move() output in Arduino Leonardo

Tags: programming, arduino-leonardo, sketch, pointer

I'm using my Arduino Leonardo as a Mouse but I'm experimenting a strange behaviour.
I put my mouse at (-1, -1) (absolute) coordinates and then I execute this code:

```
Move.move(com[curr_cmd_id].x, com[curr_cmd_id].y, 0);
```

where that point is (334, 180) (relative coords) (and I checked it through Serial console)

Now, the pointer is actually moving to the right but then it stops. Let's say it reaches the point (334, 0).

Then I tried:

```
Mouse.move(com[curr_cmd_id].x, 0, 0);
delay(500);
Mouse.move(0, com[curr_cmd_id].y, 0);
```

but still the same behaviour.

Then finally I tried this one (which it actually solves my problem but it's a dirty solution):

```
int i;
for(i=0; i<com[curr_cmd_id].x; i++){
  Mouse.move(1,0,0);
  delay(1);
}
for(i=0; i<com[curr_cmd_id].y; i++){
  Mouse.move(0,1,0);
  delay(1);
}
```

Could anybody help me in understanding what's going on here? How can I achieve a simple and direct relative movement for my pointer?
Thanks you in advance!!

Comment: So it's only moving to the right, and not up?

Comment: Only on the right and not down (considering the coordinates I expect to go down with positive y)

Comment: It looks like maybe there's something filtering a maximum "jump" in the mouse position.  What happens if your increment your for loop by more than 1 - can you experimentally discover a limit?

Comment: why result is so diffrent between : moveMouse(127, 0, 0); and for (i=1; i<= 127; i++) { moveMouse(1, 0, 0);} ?

Answer (score 1):

I struggled with this too until I realized this

> Parameters
>
> xVal: amount to move along the x-axis - signed char
>
> yVal: amount to move along the y-axis - signed char
>
> wheel: amount to move scroll wheel - signed char

Note it says signed char.

That means the value you pass to the Mouse.move is a signed 8-bit. (-128 to 127)

My work around is this below:

```
void moveMouse(int x, int y, int w){
  x = (int)x / 1.59; //Adjust these two values accordingly. I found out that 100, 100 does 
  y = (int)y / 1.58; //not move 100, 100. It moves 159, 158 for me.

  while(x!=0 || y!=0 || w!=0){
    int moveX, moveY, moveW;
    if(x > 0){
      if(x >= 100){
        moveX = 100;
      }else{
        moveX = x;
      }
    }else if (x < 0){
      if(x <= -100){
        moveX = -100;
      }else{
        moveX = x;
      }
    }else{
      moveX = 0;
    }

    if(y > 0){
      if(y >= 100){
        moveY = 100;
      }else{
        moveY = y;
      }
    }else if (y < 0){
      if(y <= -100){
        moveY = -100;
      }else{
        moveY = y;
      }
    }else{
      moveY = 0;
    }

    if(w > 0){
      if(w >= 127){
        moveW = 127;
      }else{
        moveW = w;
      }
    }else if (w < 0){
      if(w <= -128){
        moveW = -128;
      }else{
        moveW = w;
      }
    }else{
      moveW = 0;
    }

    x = x - moveX;
    y = y - moveY;
    w = w - moveW;

    Mouse.move(moveX, moveY, moveW);
  }
```

Comment: Same answer in 5 lines: `void MouseMove(int x, int y) {
  for(int i=0; (x>0)?(i<x/100):(i>x/100); (x>0)?(i++):(i--)) 
    Mouse.move((x>0)?(100):(-100), 0);
  for(int j=0; (y>0)?(j<y/100):(j>y/100); (y>0)?(j++):(j--)) 
    Mouse.move(0, (y>0)?(100):(-100));
  Mouse.move(x%100, y%100);
}`